# finding model in rails gives "ArgumentError: no receiver given"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I just change the name of one of my models, it used to be "Course", and now it's "Booking", also I have created two brand new classes called "Course" and "Lesson" that both inherit from "Booking"

I have updated all the has_many in my models from :courses to :bookings, I made sure to rename the file to booking.rb, and renamed the table in the database to bookings.

When I run this in the rails console

```
Booking.find 1
```

I get this error

```
ArgumentError: no receiver given
```

The 2nd line below is the one causing the error

```
if filter.arity <= 0
  lambda { |target, _| target.instance_exec(&filter) }
else
  lambda { |target, _| target.instance_exec(target, &filter) }
end
```

Here is the stack trace

```
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:207:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `block in call'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `each'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_initialize_callbacks'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:350:in `init_with'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:69:in `instantiate'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `block in each'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `each'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:52:in `each'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `map'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block in find_by_sql'
... 14 levels...
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
from ~/fidka_app/bin/rails:38:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It seems that there is issue with some `callback` in the model probably (not sure though). Can you paste the model callbacks?

Comment: That was it, I had  "after_initialize(&:instance_method)" there, removed it, and it works